# Connect SQLite using PDO to create a login page

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to create a login page using SQlite.  However, for some reason I have been getting error (
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\login.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\login.php on line 20)

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
   session_start();
    $error = "";
    if(@$_SESSION['login_user'] != null){
        header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
   if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = strtolower($_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = $_POST['password']; 

      $dir = 'sqlite:db.sqlite3';
        $dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");

      $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users_ WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = $dbh->query($sql);

        $row = $result->fetch();

      echo $row['username'];
      echo $row['password'];


   }
?>
```

Comment: FROM users_ maybe should be FROM users

Comment: When a query fails it returns false, that's why you can get the boolean message after if you don't chech that the execution was ok

Comment: You should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP doc: PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.  That means `$dbh->query($sql)` could return a boolean (false) if something went wrong with executing your SQL query (you should add code to handle this possibility).  The error message you got strongly suggest this is the case.

So, let's see, what could be the cause of your SQL failing.  These are possibilities ...

1. Is your table name really "users_" (note the trailing underscore) or should it be just "users".
2. Maybe the value of `$password` contains a character, like `'` (single quote) that would result in a bad SQL statement.

UPDATE (to answer comment below): You are building the entire SQL statement including data values all in PHP as a string *before PDO sees it*.  So PDO only sees the string and so it cannot know or handle special characters that should be escaped.  PDO would have to be waaaay too smart to know which characters are okay and which are not (especially if the data is an SQL injection; it would look just fine if PDO parsed it looking for characters to escape).

As it is, your code is exposed to SQL injection.  You should either 1) escape the data ...

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users_ WHERE "
    . "username = '" . $dbh->quote($myusername) . "' "
    . "and password = '" . $dbh->quote($mypassword) . "'";
```

or (MUCH BETTER!) 2) use prepared statements (PDO will do any necessary escaping as it substitutes data values for the `?` in the SQL statement)

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users_ WHERE "
    . "username = ? AND password = ?";   // note the "?" placeholders
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$myusername, $mypassword]);  // here, PDO will escape characters
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // process a $row
}
```

Comment: The real cause of error was existence of ' in $password value. Don't PDO sort SQL Injection itself as there is no need of something alternative like mysqli_real_escape_string for MySQL. Will using prepare() fix that issue?

Comment: @Skla777, I updated answer above with answer to your question.